# Image Tag Flow Problem

Tags: css, fluid-layout

i use this fluidgrid system: http://fluid.newgoldleaf.com/

I have the problem, if the first content element in a column is an image Tag, the content in the following column drops down.

It only works, if the first content element is something like a paragraph or a headline etc., and the second is an image Tag.

Why? :-)

Thankx.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the container that wraps the image an, `overflow:hidden`. This may hide your image though. seeing a working example would help...